# Check back Checkbox items which are checked previously

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, checkboxlist

I have some checkbox items inside a list as you can see from the code below and this is how I implemented.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" Name="listBox" >
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <CheckBox Foreground="Black" Content="{Binding Types}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and c# code behind,

```
        List<Items> list1;
        list1 = new List<Items>();
        list1.Add(new Items() { Types = "Checkbox1", IsSelected = false });
        list1.Add(new Items() { Types = "Checkbox2", IsSelected = false });
        list1.Add(new Items() { Types = "Checkbox3", IsSelected = false });
        list1.Add(new Items() { Types = "Checkbox4", IsSelected = false });
        list1.Add(new Items() { Types = "Checkbox5", IsSelected = false });
        list1.Add(new Items() { Types = "Checkbox6", IsSelected = false });
        this.listBox.ItemsSource = list1;
```

I just want to save the checked checkboxes and again while navigating to that page, those previously checked checkboxes should be Checked. I tried using PhoneApplicationService.Current.State but couldn't achieve my target.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you navigate away from your page you can take the list and convert it to JSON string and store it in the IsolatedStorageSettings and then when you come back retrieve the JSON string from the IsolatedStorageSettings and deserialize the JSON string to the list and populate the ListBox. You can use JSON.Net for serializing and deserializing. Install it from Nuget.

Comment: Its such a long method and I don't need Isolated storage to store. I already achieved this by saving Item source using Phone State service but getting some errors while navigating for second time. Any helpful code is highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the problem with state is that. The state is particular to a page right. PhoneApplicationService.Current.State is used when that app is tombstoned.But it will not retain the values if the page navigates to another page. The solution i gave you is a bit expensive, but it works in all situations. Even after a restart of the app.

Comment: I feel sorry that you don't know much about Phone Application States. If you save values through states, you can call it anywhere in any pages using it key values. And I also aware of Isolated Storage but can you help me with the code.

Comment: Well then its time to learn about ApplicationStates right? I'll do that.. What exactly the error that you are having? Any exceptions?

Comment: Yep, It's time for you. Am not getting any exceptions, since am saving the full itemsource in my key value, I couldn't use it efficiently. Any other method, even logic's on how to overcome this are highly appreciated.

Comment: You are right, I stand corrected. I just tried out a sample and its available trough out the app. Thank you. In your case, were you able to have the selected checkboxs restored or is this a problem about efficiency? I'll try to replicate your issue and see if i come up with something.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the value in `Settings` of the `IsolatedStorage`.

This is just a sample:

xaml:

.cs:

```
 public MainPage()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;

 }

void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (settings.Contains("CheckBox1Checked"))
        CheckBox1.Checked = settings["CheckBox1Checked"];
}

private void OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    settings["CheckBox1Checked"] = true;
    settings.Save();
}


private void OnUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    settings["CheckBox1Checked"] = false;
    settings.Save();
}
```

For more take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765076/checkbox-not-saving-state)

Hope it helps!